# How can I view my mail backup?

Tags: email, thunderbird, import, pop3

I installed the getmail4 package and created a backup of my mails over POP3.
Every mail is a seperate file containing its headers and content now.

[image]

Is there any comfortable way to view these? Can I import backup mail folders into Thunderbird or any other mail client?

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends on what command you used to take the copy. Getmail4 supports several formats including MBox (natively used by Thunderbird) and MailDir (typically used by IMAP mail stores on UNIX-like OS's).

You may want to redo the extract using the MBox format so that you can import the data directly into Thunderbird.